# making the file uploader return a promise in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, promise, sails.js

I need to upload images when creating a model, and the images are uploaded to Amazon S3 storage. The file paths to those uploaded images are then saved in the data model persisted in the database.

I am using Sails, and the file upload works by referencing to the example at  http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/file-uploads. However, I would like to make the file uploader return a promise so that the controller method can get the file paths and save it to the data model.

I have tried to use `bluebird` and the `q` libraries to promisify the `skipper-s3`:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Q = require('q');

function uploader(req, res) {
   var images = req.file('images');
   return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            images.upload({
                maxBytes:1500000,
                adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
                key: config.AMAZON_S3_KEY,
                secret: config.AMAZON_S3_SECRET,
                bucket: config.AMAZON_S3_IMGBUCKETNAME
            }, cb);
        });
}
```

**The callback `cb` is the following function:**

```
var cb = function(err, uploadedFiles) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var filePaths = [];
    if (err)  {
        sails.log.error('error in uploading image');
        deferred.reject(filePaths);
        return deferred.promise;        
    }   
    sails.log.info('success in uploading image, uploadedFiles: ', uploadedFiles);
    filePaths = uploadedFiles.map(function(file) {
        return file.extra.Location;
    });
    deferred.resolve(filePaths);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The upload works for me, but the function call `uploader` cannot resolve. I was wondering where might be wrong.